# How to include prefixLength in Elasticsearch query built using HibernateSearch QueryDSL

Tags: java, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

We're using Hibernate Search 5.10.3.Final against Elasticsearch 5.6.6 server.

In creating a fuzzy query to pass to FullTextSession::createFullTextQuery, I'm setting the editDistance and prefixLength but I noticed from the logs that the actual query sent to Elasticsearch does NOT contain the prefixLength.

This code is a grabbed from a number of separate methods, but this is the basic working flow:

```
QueryBuilder qb = fts.getSearchFactory()
    .buildQueryBuilder()
    .forEntity(Vendor.class)
    .get();

BooleanJunction namesBool = qb.bool();

String field = "vendorNames.vendorName";
String token = "rooster";

int editDistance = getEditDistance(token); //returns 1 for "rooster"
int prefixLength = getPrefixLength(token); //returns 1 for "rooster"

namesBool.must(
    qb.keyword()
        .fuzzy() //returns FuzzyContext
        .withEditDistanceUpTo(editDistance)
        .withPrefixLength(prefixLength)
        .onField(field)
        .matching(token)
        .createQuery()
);


// ...
// calling FullTextSession::createFullTextQuery
```

When the term "rooster" gets sent thru this method, it has an editDistance (fuzziness) of 1 and prefixLength of 1.

Examining the logs and seeing what gets sent to ES, I would expect to see "prefix_length" directly below "fuzziness", but it's not there:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "vendorNames.vendorName": {
            "query": "rooster",
            "fuzziness": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

1. Why does FuzzyContext allow for setting the prefixLength but not use it?
2. Is it really worth the ES performance increase to try to include prefixLength (I tested REST query calls directly to ES both with and without prefixLength and didn't notice a response time difference)?
3. How can I get prefixLength to be included in the actual query sent to ES?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does FuzzyContext allow for setting the prefixLength but not use it?

It's a bug of the Elasticsearch integration, but it wasn't reported until now: thanks! We'll try and fix it in the next development cycle: [HSEARCH-3545](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3545)

> Is it really worth the ES performance increase to try to include prefixLength (I tested REST query calls directly to ES both with and without prefixLength and didn't notice a response time difference)?

`prefixLength` is more about relevance of results than about performance. The idea is, if the user gives us a 10-character-long word, we will likely get lots of fuzzy matches, most of which are probably irrelevant. By ignoring the first 5 characters (for example), we will focus the fuzziness near the end of the word, which is likely less relevant (think "theory"/"theories", "constituting"/"constitute", etc.): that way we will get less fuzzy matches, but they will be more relevant.

At least that's the theory :)

> How can I get prefixLength to be included in the actual query sent to ES?

If you do not need support for multiple tokens, you can create a `FuzzyQuery` directly:

```
BooleanJunction namesBool = qb.bool();
String field = "vendorNames.vendorName";
String token = "rooster";
int editDistance = getEditDistance(token); //returns 1 for "rooster"
int prefixLength = getPrefixLength(token); //returns 1 for "rooster"

namesBool.must(
    new FuzzyQuery(new Term(field, token), editDistance, prefixLength)
);
```

This query will be translated correctly.

If you do need support for multiple tokens (i.e. you want a [fuzzy `match` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-fuzziness), not just a [`fuzzy` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html)), then your only solution would be to write the *whole* query as JSON and use `org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchQueries#fromJson`:

```
String field = "vendorNames.vendorName";
String token = "rooster";
int editDistance = getEditDistance(token); //returns 1 for "rooster"
int prefixLength = getPrefixLength(token); //returns 1 for "rooster"

QueryDescriptor queryDescriptor = ElasticsearchQueries.fromJson(
"{"
  + "\"query\": {"
    + "\"bool\": {"
      + "\"must\": {"
        + "\"match\": {"
          + "\"" + field + "\": {"
            + "\"query\": \"" + token + "\","
            + "\"fuzziness\": " + editDistance + ","
            + "\"prefix_length\": " + prefixLength
          + "}"
        + "}"
      + "}"
    + "}"
  + "}"
+ "}"
);

List<?> result = session.createFullTextQuery( queryDescriptor, MyEntity.class )
                .list();
```

Yes it's a mouthful... We're improving things in Hibernate Search 6.

Comment: Good to know!  Thanks, I think I can use your suggestion of building a new FuzzyQuery.

Comment: Could you finish your explanation about prefixLength that starts with "The idea is, if the user gives us"?  I think it got chopped off.

Comment: Right, sorry. Done.

Comment: This might morph into a separate question but in changing from a Match query to the FuzzyQuery as suggested, I noticed transpositions now default to false and using `new FuzzyQuery(new Term(field, token), editDistance, prefixLength, FuzzyQuery.defaultMaxExpansions, true)`, it doesn't get translated to the ES query (ironically, similar to prefix_length being ignored in the Match query).  Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I you want transpositions, your only option in Search 5 would be to write the whole query as JSON...

Comment: If you badly need it, you can always open a ticket or better submit a PR, this should be an easy fix and we should be able to integrate it in the next 5.11 release.